# pro tools auto generated regions

Tags: pro-tools

I have this error message it keeps asking me if I want to delete these auto generated regions, what if I do will it effect the session in anyway?

> You are currently not displaying auto-created regions in the region
>   list. However, through editing, a large number of these auto-created
>   regions have accumulated in the background.
>
> Large numbers of regions tend to slow down pro-tools editing and save
>   operations. If you are not using these auto-created regions, you
>   should delete them in order to keep Pro-Tools as responsive as
>   possible.
>
> Would you like to delete all unused auto-created regions now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will only delete unused regions, meaning regions that are not used in any tracks in the edit window.  So if you delete them, everything will play back as before, and you can continue editing.

The only reason you wouldn't want to delete these unused regions is if you may undo the editing that created them.